# Extending PDF Printer or write my own driver?

Tags: pdf, printing, driver

Background (simplified):
We are sending PDFs digitally to people through a system. PDFs are dropped to folder and then picked up by the sending system.
But now we are facing some validation that is mandatory by the system, so we need to provide feedback for those PDFs that does not pass.

CLARIFICATION: What we are sending out are PDFs but the origin may be a textdocument, worddocument etc. The idea of building our own printerdriver is it would be very userfriendly.

Question:

1. Is it possible to add validation to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer? So if a user tries to print something that doesn't pass the validation template it generates a message?
2. If I were to write my own printer driver, which one should I start with? It would be ideal to be able to extend the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer. C++ or C# does not matter.

I have found Microsofts github page with drivers.

[image: Microsoft Github printer drivers]

Comment: If PDFs are dropped in a folder, can you process them directly instead of re-rendering through a PDF printer driver? Adding a printer driver adds significant complexity. If you do need a printer driver, you could look at the Win2PDF plug-in interface: https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/win2pdf-plug-in.html

Comment: I've added a clarification to my initial post.

Win2PDF looks like nice plugin, but not exactly what we are looking for.

Right now I have the validation part done, what I'm looking for is a package that can be installed as a printer and used in applications to "print" to a folder.

Comment: I don't want to send anything to a printer. The idea is to create a driver and install it so it is selectable in a users Word applikation (for example) when they want to send something to the system that sends PDFs digitally.

In this "printer" the docuent will be transformed into a PDF, validated and saved to a folder for the next system.

PROS: Userfriendly, the user don't have to manually handle file, they can send it directly to the next system. Validation is instant and they get feedback if the document doesn't pass the validation.

CONS: I have to build a printer driver.

Comment: We could use the "Microsoft Print to PDF" and then print it to a folder where a validationprogram picks up PDFs and validates them.

PROS: A lot simpler than writing our own printerdriver.
CONS: Much less userfriendly as the feedback on the validation process is not instant.

Comment: After some discussion with an architect we have decided to ditch the effort to write our own driver, we will pursue another solution.